# Javascript object "is not defined" error after ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude

Tags: c#, javascript, scriptmanager

I have an external js file that is basically a js object. I am using the ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude method to include the file on page, and after that I am using the ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock method to call a method of the js object, but am getting a js error of 'DynamicLoadingPanel is not defined'. I know the method call works when I have it in the aspx page, but I think I'm getting the error cause of the timing when the ScriptManager registers the script block. I currently have the Registers in the Page_Load event, below is my code. Can someone please help me understand what's going on here. Thanks.

### Page_Load Event

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.ClientScript.IsClientScriptIncludeRegistered("DynamicLoadingPanel"))
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude(Page, typeof(Page), "DynamicLoadingPanel", "~/dynamicLoadingPanel.js");
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, typeof(Page), "set_LoadingPanelID", "DynamicLoadingPanel.set_loadingPanelID('modalLayer');", true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using the full path of the source instead of ~/dynamicLoadingPanel.js ?

Also, do you get a callback on your Page when something has loaded?  Perhaps you need to wait for that before making the call on the second line.

Comment: No callback, and I removed the "~/" from the url since the file is in the same folder and still no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a few trial and errors, I finally found the correct way to include an external js file. So for all those that come across this issue, I hope this saves you a couple frustrating hours.

To include your file you must get an object of the current ScriptManager and add the file to the Scripts collection. Below is an example.

```
ScriptManager sm = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page);
ScriptReference sr = new ScriptReference("~/scripts/dynamicLoadingPanel.js");
if (!sm.Scripts.Contains(sr))
    sm.Scripts.Add(sr);
```

Comment: UPDATE: If you are needing to register a script with a SharePoint app you would need to use the ScriptLink control and place the script in the Layouts 1033 folder. At least that's the directory layout for my app, which I believe is OOB. Please don't quote me on that. Hope this helps.

Comment: Very helpful answer. Additionally, make sure you have a ScriptManager on the page, otherwise your `sm` variable will be `null`.

Comment: This helped me so much. I had a javascript function within a user control that was within an update panel, and every time the javascript function was called, I'd get an exception that the function wasn't found. Implementing your solution worked great!

Answer (score 0):

or you could do something like this...

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Binds the name of the script by.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="control">
        /// The control.
        /// </param>
        /// <param name="scriptName">
        /// Name of the script.
        /// </param>
        public static void BindScriptByName(this Control control, string scriptName)
        {
            if (control.Page == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var sm = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(control.Page);
            if (sm == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (sm.Scripts.Count(s => s.Name == scriptName) == 0)
            {
                sm.Scripts.Add(new ScriptReference { Name = scriptName });
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Registers the script definitions.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Call this on Application_Startup in Global.asax.
        /// </remarks>
        public static void RegisterScriptDefinitions()
        {
            var jqueryScriptResDef = new ScriptResourceDefinition
            {
                Path = "~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.min.js",
                DebugPath = "~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.2.js",
                CdnPath = "http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js",
                CdnDebugPath = "http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.2.js"
            };
            ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("jQuery", jqueryScriptResDef);

            var jquerySuperFishMenuScriptResDef = new ScriptResourceDefinition
            {
                Path = "~/Scripts/jquery.superfishmenu.js",
                DebugPath = "~/Scripts/jquery.superfishmenu.js",
                CdnPath = "~/Scripts/jquery.superfishmenu.js",
                CdnDebugPath = "~/Scripts/jquery.superfishmenu.js"
            };
            ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("jQuery.SuperFishMenu", jquerySuperFishMenuScriptResDef);

            var jqueryIdTabsScriptResDef = new ScriptResourceDefinition
            {
                Path = "~/Scripts/jquery.idTabs.min.js",
                DebugPath = "~/Scripts/jquery.idTabs.min.js",
                CdnPath = "~/Scripts/jquery.idTabs.min.js",
                CdnDebugPath = "~/Scripts/jquery.idTabs.min.js",
            };
            ScriptManager.ScriptResourceMapping.AddDefinition("jQuery.idTabs", jqueryIdTabsScriptResDef);
        }
```

This lets you call RegisterScriptDefinitions in your Global.asax and then load them up by their Name... BindScriptByName("jQuery");