# Why doesn't textbox onchange event fire correctly within asp.net user control?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, asp.net-ajax

I have 2 textboxes that I'm trying to capture the onchange event for. These textboxes are within a user control that is within an asp.net updatepanel. Every time I change the textbox text, I receive a "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected" error that doesn't provide any other helpful information.

Here is the code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ResetOrientationImage() {
            var width = (+document.getElementById('<%= txtWidth.ClientID %>').value);
            var height = (+document.getElementById('<%= txtHeight.ClientID %>').value);
            if (width > height) {
                document.getElementById('<%= imgOrientation.ClientID %>').src = "images/buttons/Landscape.png";
            } else {
                document.getElementById('<%= imgOrientation.ClientID %>').src = "images/buttons/Portrait.png";
            }
        }
</script>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtWidth" runat="server" Width="50px" onchange="ResetOrientationImage()" Text="0"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtHeight" runat="server" Width="50px" onchange="ResetOrientationImage()" Text="0"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Image ID="imgOrientation" ImageUrl="~/images/buttons/Portrait.png" runat="server" />
```

I thought it must be a problem with the javascript, but I put this exact code into a standalone .aspx page and it executes correctly with no errors.

**EDIT**
Upon looking in Firebug, the real error is that the ResetOrientationImage function cannot be found when the page executes. If I move the javascript out of the user control onto the page itself, it works as I would expect. Why can't the javascript live in the user control?

Comment: Something is messing up with you javascript elsewhere, look for an error in the page that you are adding the userControl

Comment: Have you looked at it with IE8+'s JavaScript console which points to the error? Have you debugged what `document.getElementById('<%= txtWidth.ClientID %>').value` and the other one return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled upon this question which gave me my answer:

[Javascript object "is not defined" error after ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313882/javascript-object-is-not-defined-error-after-scriptmanager-registerclientscrip)

I moved my javascript function into an external file and referenced it in the user control code behind like this:

```
    ScriptManager sm = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page);
    ScriptReference sr = new ScriptReference("~/scripts/ResetOrientationImage.js");
    if (!sm.Scripts.Contains(sr))
       sm.Scripts.Add(sr);
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things here:

```
var width = (+document.getElementById('<%= txtWidth.ClientID %>').value);
var height = (+document.getElementById('<%= txtHeight.ClientID %>').value);
```

The "+" at the beginning before "document" is invalid.

`width` and `height` are going to be strings. You need to make them integers:

```
var width = parseInt(document.getElementById('<%= txtWidth.ClientID %>').value);
```

Also - please how your HTML **output**, not your .NET **source**. The problem is on the client, not the server.

Comment: Thank you for setting me straight on parseInt - I corrected that in my code.